# Compile libav for Android x86_64

Tags: android, android-ndk, x86-64, libav

I'm trying to compile lib for all architecture, including 64 bits.
The script I created works fine for **armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, and x86.**
It fails for **mips**, and would probably fail for **mips64** as well, but I don't care that much about them ; it is secondary to the main problem that I have : I care about x86_64, and this one won't compile.

**EDIT** : it fails for x86 as well. Compilation error logs at the end of post.

Here is what the script does :

1. create a standalone toolchain : works like a charm
2. use that toolchain to configure lib :

> ./configure --arch=x86_64 --cpu=x86_64 --cross-prefix=/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-  --target-os=android --sysroot="/some/path/Library/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64/" --extra-cflags=" -O3 -fpic -DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 -march=atom -ffast-math -msse3 -mfpmath=sse " --extra-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath-link=/some/path/Library/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib -L/some/path/Library/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm" --enable-shared --disable-symver

This seems to configure well, config.log does not fire any error, except the following warning (which I get for every architecture anyway) :

```
WARNING: /some/path/Documents/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-pkg-config not found, library detection may fail.
```

3. compile : make -j 8. I get .so files properly generated, but if I take a closer look at logs, I get errors at the end (sorry I can't paste the whole logs, it is to long) :

> CC  libswscale/yuv2rgb.o
>       AR  libavformat/libavformat.a
>       YASM    libswscale/x86/scale.o
>       AR  libavcodec/libavcodec.a
>       AR  libavresample/libavresample.a
>       AR  libavutil/libavutil.a
>       CC  avconv.o
>       CC  cmdutils.o
>       CC  avconv_opt.o
>       CC  avconv_filter.o
>       CC  avprobe.o
>       HOSTCC  doc/print_options.o
>       AR  libavdevice/libavdevice.a
>       LD  libavutil/libavutil.so.54
>       AR  libavfilter/libavfilter.a
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libc.so
>   while searching for c
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libm.so
>   while searching for m
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libm.so
>   while searching for m
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libz.so
>   while searching for z
>       LD  libavresample/libavresample.so.2
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libc.so
>   while searching for c
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libm.so
>   while searching for m
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libm.so
>   while searching for m
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libz.so
>   while searching for z
>       LD  libavcodec/libavcodec.so.56
>       HOSTLD  doc/print_options
>       GENTEXI doc/avoptions_format.texi
>       GENTEXI doc/avoptions_codec.texi
>       POD doc/avprobe.pod
>       POD doc/avconv.pod
>       MAN doc/avprobe.1
>       MAN doc/avconv.1
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libc.so
>   while searching for c
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libm.so
>   while searching for m
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libm.so
>   while searching for m
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libz.so
>   while searching for z
>       LD  libavformat/libavformat.so.56
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libc.so
>   while searching for c
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libm.so
>   while searching for m
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libm.so
>   while searching for m
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libz.so
>   while searching for z
>       LD  libavdevice/libavdevice.so.55
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libc.so
>   while searching for c
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libm.so
>   while searching for m
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libm.so
>   while searching for m
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libz.so
>   while searching for z
>       LD  libswscale/libswscale.so.3
>       AR  libswscale/libswscale.a
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libc.so
>   while searching for c
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libm.so
>   while searching for m
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libm.so
>   while searching for m
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libz.so
>   while searching for z
>       LD  libavfilter/libavfilter.so.5
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libc.so
>   while searching for c
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libm.so
>   while searching for m
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libm.so
>   while searching for m
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libz.so
>   while searching for z
>       LD  avconv
>       LD  avprobe
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libc.so
>   while searching for c
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libm.so
>   while searching for m
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libm.so
>   while searching for m
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libz.so
>   while searching for z
>       libavcodec/libavcodec.so: error: undefined reference to '__powidf2'
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       make: *** [avprobe] Error 1
>       make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libc.so
>   while searching for c
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libm.so
>   while searching for m
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libm.so
>   while searching for m
>       /Volumes/diskE/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
>   warning: skipping incompatible
>   /some/pathLibrary/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64//usr/lib/libz.so
>   while searching for z
>       libavcodec/libavcodec.so: error: undefined reference to '__powidf2'
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       make: *** [avconv] Error 1

Errors compiling x86, after configuring with : ./configure --arch=x86 --cpu=x86 --cross-prefix=/some/path/Documents/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86/bin/i686-linux-android-  --target-os=android --sysroot="/some/path/Library/Android/ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-x86/" --extra-cflags=" -O3 -fpic -DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 -march=atom -ffast-math -msse3 -mfpmath=sse " --extra-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath-link=/some/path/Library/Android/ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-x86//usr/lib -L/some/path/Library/Android/ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-x86//usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm" --enable-shared

```
                                ^
CC  libswscale/x86/yuv2rgb.o
CC  libswscale/yuv2rgb.o
AR  libavformat/libavformat.a
YASM    libswscale/x86/scale.o
AR  libavcodec/libavcodec.a
AR  libavresample/libavresample.a
AR  libavutil/libavutil.a
CC  avconv.o
CC  cmdutils.o
CC  avconv_opt.o
CC  avconv_filter.o
CC  avprobe.o
HOSTCC  doc/print_options.o
AR  libavdevice/libavdevice.a
LD  libavutil/libavutil.so.54
AR  libavfilter/libavfilter.a
HOSTLD  doc/print_options
LD  libavresample/libavresample.so.2
GENTEXI doc/avoptions_format.texi
GENTEXI doc/avoptions_codec.texi
POD doc/avprobe.pod
POD doc/avconv.pod
LD  libavcodec/libavcodec.so.56
MAN doc/avprobe.1
MAN doc/avconv.1
LD  libavformat/libavformat.so.56
LD  libavdevice/libavdevice.so.55
LD  libswscale/libswscale.so.3
AR  libswscale/libswscale.a
LD  libavfilter/libavfilter.so.5
LD  avconv
LD  avprobe
libavdevice/libavdevice.so: error: undefined reference to '__divdi3'
libavdevice/libavdevice.so:libavdevice/libavdevice.so:  errorerror: undefined reference to ': __moddi3'
libavformatundefined reference to '__moddi3'
libavformat/libavformat.so/libavformat.so: error: undefined reference: error to : undefined'__udivdi3' reference to '__udivdi3'
libavformat/
libavformat/libavformat.so: errorlibavformat.so: error: : undefined reference undefined referenceto ' to '__umoddi3'
libavcodec/__umoddi3'
libavcodec.so: errorlibavcodec/: libavcodec.so: error: undefined reference to '__powidf2'
avconv.c:1434: error: undefined referenceundefined reference to '__powidf2 to '
'__divdi3'
avconv.c:1441: error: undefined reference to '__divdi3'
avconv.c:1434: error: undefined reference to '__divdi3'
avconv.c:1441: error: undefined reference to '__divdi3'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [avprobe] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [avconv] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't specifying any `--cross-prefix` or `--cc`, which means that it will use your host system compiler (OS X) for compiling for android - this only actually fails when it tries to link to the android libs.

To actually make this work as intended, add `--cross-prefix=x86_64-linux-android-` to your configure line. (I assume you did something such to make it work for the other architectures as well.)

Edit: I misread, and you actually do supply `--cross-prefix` just fine.

Remove all of your `--extra-cflags` and `--extra-ldflags` - they are redundant and conflicting. If you have a concrete need or case for any particular of them, then you may reconsider adding some of the individual flags, but most of them are just redundant. In this case, the `-L` option that points to your sysroot's lib directory seems to be causing your issues - setting this via `--sysroot` already is enough and the `-L` and `-Wl,-rpath-link` are just redundant.

In general, don't blindly add large hordes of options - more isn't better when it comes to compiler options. Only add the ones you concretely understand and know you need.

If you use `--target-os=android`, you don't need `--disable-symver` - that option was only needed before android was added as a separate value for `--target-os`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. You are right, I use --cross-prefix for other arch. But seems to me that I do it for x86_64 as well : --cross-prefix=/some/path/usingLibAV/toolchains/x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android- Or did I miss your point ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I somehow missed that you used that (especially when the original version of the post talked about the version of your host system compiler). I tried your command line and I'll edit the answer with a solution that actually works.

Comment: It works for x86, x86_64, and even mips ! Thanks ! I still get errors for mips64 at compile time however  : 
/var/folders/pk/x0zcs6n571372r3x0yq38pfc0005y7/T//ccel6m70.s: Assembler messages:
/var/folders/pk/x0zcs6n571372r3x0yq38pfc0005y7/T//ccel6m70.s:96: Error: opcode not supported on this processor: mips64r6 (mips64r6) `lwl $4,3($2)' Any idea ?

Comment: Apparently there's some snippets of mips64 inline assembly that lack the right checks (since the android mips64 ABI baseline doesn't include support for those features) - you can work around this by adding `--disable-inline-asm` for now.

Comment: Thanks ! That worked : ./configure --arch=mips64 --cross-prefix=/some/path/Documents/usingLibAV/toolchains/mips64el/bin/mips64el-linux-android- --disable-inline-asm  --target-os=android --sysroot="/some/path/Library/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-mips64/" --extra-cflags="" --extra-ldflags="" --enable-shared